# np where statement gets: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I am writing for following line of code:

```
holiday['real_or_not'] = np.where((holiday['transferred']=='False',1,0))
holiday
```

Minimum reproducible example:

```
date        type   locale    locale_name  description    transferred

2012-03-02  False  locale     Manta        Fundacion de Manta  False
2012-03-02  False  Regional   Regional     Gunanta              True
```

I am getting:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any ideas why? I write a fairly similar `np.where` statement on a different pandas data frame in my code and it works perfectly fine. No idea why it would work there but not in here.

Comment: can you show a sample of your data so I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yep I just added

Comment: Test the parts? What happens if you only do `(holiday['transferred']=='False',1,0)`? Or only `holiday['transferred']=='False'`? Or only `holiday['transferred']`? Locate the problem.

Comment: `np.where((...))` Are the double parentheses intentional?

Comment: Remove the quotes from around False.

Comment: @StefanPochmann when I do your first suggestion it gives me: (array([0, 1]),) for your 2nd suggestion I get a False or True outputted for every value. John Gordon, are you saying they should not be there? I used them in the same type of np.where statement elsewhere and it worked

Comment: oh my god damn, it was easy. Thank you Josh Gordan, it was the double quotes. How can I checkmark your answer? The thing I don't get then is why it worked in my other code...

Comment: Not a direct response to your question about `np.where`, but FWIW you could just use `eq` to accomplish the same result: `df['real_or_not'] = df.transferred.eq('False').astype(int)`

Comment: @mkheifetz I'll let someone else answer who is familiar with numpy and can explain exactly what was happening.  I just thought the double parens seemed suspicious.

Comment: Thanks! if you would put it as an answer I would except to give you points....

Comment: Not sure why you need `np.where` here for a simple 0/1. Use `.astype(int)` instead.

Comment: and why is it that .astype works in this case?

Comment: can any of you guys look at my other stackoverflow question here, I tried asking it 2 times with different titles and do not get any responses at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996444/graph-only-partially-displaying-in-jupyter-notebook-output

Comment: `real_or_not` is an awful name for a boolean! Does 1 mean real, or does 0 mean real?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to remove the extra parenthesis. Because it creates a tuple and you give `np.where` one argument, the tuple, instead off three arguments.
This means this tuple is interpreted as as the condition because the second and third argument are optional:

```
where(condition, [x, y])
```

> Return elements, either from `x` or `y`, depending on `condition`.
>   If only `condition` is given, return `condition.nonzero()`.

Calling a function with just one argument, you can add as many extra parentheses as you like. As soon as you add a comma, you create a tuple, an you cannot do this anymore without changing how the arguments are given to the function.

Assuming the column `transferred` is bool, you can reverse your logic:

```
holiday['real_or_not'] = np.where(holiday['transferred'], 0, 1)
```

Result:

```
             type    locale locale_name description  transferred  real_or_not
date                                                                         
2012-03-02  False    locale       Manta   Fundacion        False            1
2012-03-02  False  Regional    Regional     Gunanta         True            0
```

An alternative solution without `np.where`:

```
holiday['real_or_not'] = (~holiday.transferred).astype(int)
```